# Ink e2e tests with custom environment

Tags: ink, testing, chain-extension, e2e

I have an ink! contract that uses a custom environment that contains custom chain extensions.

I am trying to write e2e tests for this contract however there is a problem.

Instantiate the contract how I would normally do won't work:

```rust
let constructor = ContractRef::new();
let address = client
                .instantiate("foo", &ink_e2e::alice(), constructor, 0, None)
                .await
                .expect("instantiate failed")
                .account_id;
```

since the `ContractRef` is created with the default environment:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> contracts/xc-regions/src/lib.rs:231:51
    |
231 |                 .instantiate("foo", &ink_e2e::alice(), constructor, 0, None)
    |                  -----------                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `CreateBuilder<DefaultEnvironment, ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>`, found `CreateBuilder<ExtendedEnvironment, ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>`
    |                  |
    |                  arguments to this method are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected struct `CreateBuilder<DefaultEnvironment, _, _, _, _, Set<ExecutionInput<_>>, _, Set<ReturnType<_>>>`
               found struct `CreateBuilder<ExtendedEnvironment, XcRegionsRef, _, _, _, Set<ExecutionInput<ArgumentList<ArgumentListEnd, ArgumentListEnd>>>, _, Set<ReturnType<XcRegionsRef>>>`
note: method defined here
   --> /Users/sergejsakac/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ink_e2e-4.3.0/src/client.rs:467:18
    |
467 |     pub async fn instantiate<ContractRef, Args, R>(
```

What would be the optimal way to instantiate a contract that uses a custom environment in an e2e test?

I tried to make this work by setting the proper environment to for the client that is passed as an argument to the e2e test, however that does not resolve the issue:

```rust
async fn test_1(mut client: ink_e2e::Client<C, environment::ExtendedEnvironment>) -> E2EResult<()> { }
```

Comment: can you share the link to the code?